# How does the inheritance of the constructor in Scala work?

Tags: scala, inheritance

```scala
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int) {
  def this(xArg: Int) = {
    this(xArg, 0)
    println("constructor")
  }
}
class TalkPoint(x: Int, y: Int) extends Point(x, y) {
  def talk() = {
    println("my position is (" + x + "," + y + ")")
  }
}
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val p = new TalkPoint(0, 0)
    p.talk()
  }
}
```

Here is an example program in Scala.
I am confused by the missing result "constructor " .

where is the constructor of the parent class Point ?

Comment: The body of the class its is constructor. The `this` method is just an auxiliary constructor _(a feature that is rarely used IME)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is actually part of the definition of the class:
`class Point(val x:Int, val y:Int)`. This line defines not only `Point`'s primary constructor that takes two `Int`s, by using `val`, it has made `x` and `y` read-only fields of the `Point` class. `def this(xArg:Int)` is what is called an auxiliary constructor, and notice how it calls the primary constructor (as all auxiliary constructors in Scala must do): `this(xArg,0)`. In Java, `Point`'s definition is roughly equivalent to

```
class Point {
  public final int x, y;

  public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  public Point(int x) {
    this(x,0);
    System.out.println("constructor");
  }
}
```

The line `class TalkPoint(x:Int,y:Int) extends Point(x,y)` not only defines the class `TalkPoint`, it also defines its primary constructor, declares it is a subclass of `Point`, and even calls `Point`'s primary constructor. In Java, something like

```
class TalkPoint extends Point {
  public TalkPoint(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
  }
// ...
}
```

In your main method, you call `TalkPoint`'s primary constructor, which in turn calls `Point`'s primary constructor, and at no point is `Point`'s auxiliary constructor invoked, and thus nothing is printed. Try creating a `Point`, however, with its auxiliary constructor: `val p = new Point(42)`